# Why a VSTS build definition when "getting resources" creates a repository with no branches and detached?

Tags: git, powershell, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have created a build definition in VSTS. I want to run a powerShell script right after the "get sources".

While "getting sources" phase I can see that some branches are being created:

```
From https://domain.visualstudio.com/_git/main
* [new branch]      develop           -> origin/develop
* [new branch]      master            -> origin/master
.......
```

Then it checks out the latest commit on a detached HEAD:

```
Checking out files: 100% (16011/16011), done.
Note: checking out '2c5ac1a6dab64603656be2610dc5c2c627b916d4'.
You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
HEAD is now at 2c5ac1a...  "Merge develop to master"
```

Then when it is time for my powerShell script there are no branches created, when I issue a

```
"git branch -v"
```

I see this :

```
 2016-11-30T10:42:26.6370529Z * (HEAD detached at 41e7eb4) 41e7eb4 first commit
```

Moreover, when I try to create checkout or create new branches in my powerShell script they appear as "red lines (errors)":

```
2016-11-30T10:42:26.6370529Z * (HEAD detached at 41e7eb4) 41e7eb4 first commit
2016-11-30T10:42:27.0110730Z ##[error]Previous HEAD position was 41e7eb4... first commit
2016-11-30T10:42:27.7881014Z ##[error]Switched to a new branch 'develop'
2016-11-30T10:42:27.9670995Z ##[error] * [new branch]      test -> test
2016-11-30T10:42:28.1945915Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 0 and     had 3 error(s) written to the error stream.
2016-11-30T10:42:28.1955965Z ##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script
```

Where are the rest of the branches created during the "get resources" phase? Why do I have a detached HEAD? And why I cannot checkout/create branches?

Thanks,

---

**--UPDATE--**
My build is able to create branches and push them directly to the remote. I needed to grant "contribute" and "branch creation" access to my build service account. However, I still get errors that make my build red, although branches and commits are actually created and pushed to the remote.

**My script** will be the following (I simpliefied it)(it is an inline PowerShell script):

```
git branch -a -v
git fetch --all
git branch -a
git checkout -b master remotes/origin/master

git checkout -b testBranch
Out-File -FilePath auto-file.txt
git add .
git commit -m "just created an auto commit"
git push -u origin testBranch
```

**And here is the corresponding Log:**

```
2016-12-09T08:05:14.9777018Z ##[section]Starting: Build
2016-12-09T08:05:14.9897018Z Current agent version: '2.109.1'
2016-12-09T08:05:15.6197698Z Downloading task: PowerShell
2016-12-09T08:05:16.6935776Z ##[section]Starting: Get Sources
2016-12-09T08:05:16.7755760Z Syncing repository: main (TfsGit)
2016-12-09T08:05:16.7806005Z Prepending Path environment variable with    directory containing 'git.exe'.
2016-12-09T08:05:16.7925998Z ##[command]git version
2016-12-09T08:05:16.9935896Z ##[command]git init "C:\a\1\s"
2016-12-09T08:05:17.0525625Z Initialized empty Git repository in C:/a/1/s/.git/
2016-12-09T08:05:17.0565864Z ##[command]git remote add origin https://domain  .visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject/_git/main
2016-12-09T08:05:17.0795632Z ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
2016-12-09T08:05:17.1035633Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.https://domain   .visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject/_git/main.extraheader
2016-12-09T08:05:17.1337092Z ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
2016-12-09T08:05:17.1597344Z ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ********" fetch --tags --prune --progress origin
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1333289Z remote: 
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote:                    vSTs           
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote:                  vSTSVSTSv        
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote:                vSTSVSTSVST        
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote: VSTS         vSTSVSTSVSTSV        
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote: VSTSVS     vSTSVSTSV STSVS        
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote: VSTSVSTSvsTSVSTSVS   TSVST        
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote: VS  tSVSTSVSTSv      STSVS        
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote: VS   tSVSTSVST       SVSTS        
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote: VS tSVSTSVSTSVSts    VSTSV        
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote: VSTSVST    SVSTSVSTs VSTSV        
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote: VSTSv        STSVSTSVSTSVS        
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote:                VSTSVSTSVST        
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote:                  VSTSVSTs        
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote:                    VSTs    (TM)        
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote: 
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote:  Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Services        
2016-12-09T08:05:18.1343246Z remote: 
2016-12-09T08:05:18.2981730Z From https://domain  .visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject/_git/main
2016-12-09T08:05:18.2981730Z  * [new branch]      develop    -> origin/develop
2016-12-09T08:05:18.2981730Z  * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3001809Z ##[command]git checkout --progress --force 7af1f2611269277da2c520b84148844e650acc4f
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3241819Z Note: checking out '7af1f2611269277da2c520b84148844e650acc4f'.
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3241819Z 
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3241819Z You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3241819Z changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3241819Z state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3241819Z 
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3241819Z If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3241819Z do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3241819Z 
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3241819Z   git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3241819Z 
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3241819Z HEAD is now at 7af1f26... try to fix cachedconfig issue
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3261731Z ##[command]git config http.https://domain  .visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject/_git/main.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: bearer ********"
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3491840Z ##[section]Finishing: Get Sources
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3511738Z ##[section]Starting: PowerShell Script
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3811752Z ==============================================================================
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3811752Z Task         : PowerShell
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3811752Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3821755Z Version      : 1.2.1
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3821755Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3821755Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613736)
2016-12-09T08:05:18.3821755Z ==============================================================================
2016-12-09T08:05:18.4611894Z ##[command]. 'C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Temp\928a835e-178f-40c1-8ba5-61da96fc8fc7.ps1' 
2016-12-09T08:05:19.1941140Z * (HEAD detached at 7af1f26) 7af1f26 try to fix cachedconfig issue
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.2081155Z   remotes/origin/develop 7af1f26 try to fix cachedconfig issue
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.2090954Z   remotes/origin/master  41e7eb4 first commit
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.2090954Z Fetching origin
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.5648482Z * (HEAD detached at 7af1f26)
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.5648482Z   remotes/origin/develop
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.5648482Z   remotes/origin/master
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.5909153Z ##[error]Previous HEAD position was 7af1f26... try to fix cachedconfig issue
 Switched to a new branch 'master'

 2016-12-09T08:05:19.5939144Z Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6609174Z ##[error]Switched to a new branch 'testBranch'

 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6609174Z [testBranch 847ac8b] just created an auto commit
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6619147Z  Committer: buildguest <buildguest>
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6619147Z Your name and email address were configured automatically based
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6619147Z on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6619147Z You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly. Run the
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6619147Z following command and follow the instructions in your editor to edit
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6619147Z your configuration file:
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6619147Z 
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6619147Z     git config --global --edit
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6619147Z 
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6619147Z After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6619147Z 
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6619147Z     git commit --amend --reset-author
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6619147Z 
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6619147Z  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 2016-12-09T08:05:19.6619147Z  create mode 100644 auto-file.txt
 2016-12-09T08:05:20.4268088Z ##[error]To https://domain .visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject/_git/main

 2016-12-09T08:05:20.4268088Z Branch testBranch set up to track remote branch testBranch from origin.
 2016-12-09T08:05:20.6018082Z ##[error] * [new branch]      testBranch -> testBranch

 2016-12-09T08:05:20.8482358Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 0 and had 4 error(s) written to the error stream.
 2016-12-09T08:05:20.8492359Z ##[section]Finishing: PowerShell Script
 2016-12-09T08:05:20.8502361Z ##[section]Starting: Post Job Cleanup
 2016-12-09T08:05:20.8562360Z Cleaning any cached credential from repository: main (Git)
 2016-12-09T08:05:20.8602360Z ##[command]git config --unset-all http.https://domain .visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject/_git/main.extraheader
 2016-12-09T08:05:20.8872360Z ##[command]git remote set-url origin https://domain  .visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject/_git/main
 2016-12-09T08:05:20.9142348Z ##[command]git remote set-url --push origin https://domain .visualstudio.com/MyFirstProject/_git/main
 2016-12-09T08:05:20.9342662Z ##[section]Finishing: Post Job Cleanup
 2016-12-09T08:05:20.9352355Z ##[section]Finishing: Build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused because git for windows and powershell have an issue with standard Input/Output/Error mapping and powershell interpretes informations as errors.
Replacing the powershell script by a batch file and using the corresponding task worked around the problem.

Comment: I needed to grant my "build service account" with the rights to create branches and contribute to the repository.

Comment: did you need to run a special command to switch back to attached mode?

Comment: I just checkout out a local master branch: git checkout -b master remotes/origin/master

Comment: That + the rights and you can do what you need except you get an error right? I suggest you delete the other post, edit this one with your progression and we'll start from here. Can you provide the content of your script? Can you switch all commands to verbose mode and put the output here?

Comment: have you tried to checkout the current branch (to resolve the detached head state) before doing anything else? and then right after to set username and email. I'm just curious how it's going to react.

Comment: since I am in a detached head at first, I do not know what you mean by "current branch". Are you referring to the "default" one? I do not what to set email and usename, since I want the build process to appear as the author of commits...

Comment: I meant "reattaching state" by checking out the current branch.

Comment: I tried to checkout develop (the branch pointing to the detached commit) and still have the same errors --> switching to branches raises errors... I also tried configuring the name and email. nothing changed

Comment: Thanks for trying, I'm curious if it might simply be a standard IO config problem now. If you put all that in a bat file and use the execute batch script instead, do you get the same result?

Comment: Brilliant!! It works! :-) So if i write in on a .bat file and use the "execute batch script" it work all right. If on the other hand I use the the inline Powerscript or run the powerShell script from a file it doesn't. Now, do you know what should I do so that I can run a powerShell (my full script uses an "invoque-webrequest" function which i do not know the counterpart in basch )

Comment: You can use some powershell from a batch file doing something like `@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('url'))"` should work. (or replace the powershell). Or alternatively you can start a batch process from powershell for your git commands. But you'll loose standard IOE doing so. I'll update my answer so you can mark it.